# Pre fill Model field when created , with values of Database MVC 4 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to prefill a model with some values that are stored in the database. They are kind of contsants so i don´t want to fill them in every controller.
The Field is Agrupaciones  and it is a *List* of *AgrupacionChequeo* database stored items

```
 public class FormModelConfigurarAreaItem
{
    [Required]
    public int PuntoMaestroAreaId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int AgrupacionChequeoId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AgrupacionChequeo> Agrupaciones { get; set; }
}
```

I want that when I instantiate this object, t has prefilled the list of Agrupaciones, something like

```
public FormModelConfigurarAreaItem(){ 
      Agrupaciones =database.AgrupacionChequeo.toList();
}
```

Some ideas?Thanks all of you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok the anser was in the question!!

```
    public FormModelConfigurarAreaItem()
    {
        DatabaseEntities db=new DatabaseEntities ();
        Agrupaciones = db.AgrupacionChequeos.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I don't thinks you would want to have access to the db from your model  ~Best Practices~

Comment: why not? It wotks fine,Do you have any alternative? –

Comment: There's something that is called 'Best Practices'. Its your own choice of course, but usually you want to populate your model from within your controller.

Comment: Yes you are right, but i Don´t know how to do it in other way. I have the problem that the model sometimes is generated via Javascript , so it cannot be populated allways from a controller.

Comment: What do ou mean generated via JavaScript?

Comment: Yes,I have some views whith a button "Add new Row"(javascript)  and it adds a new row to the collections of items in the Form with a given class  of the Model(in this case a FormModelConfigurarAreaItem)

Comment: @user, it is best to populate your model in some sort of data access layer, not inside the controller. The controller will just communicate with the DL to get the model

Answer (score 0):

Since FormModelConfigurarAreaItem is sometimes loaded via javascript in a dynamic List of a View. Would you recommend to follow this tutorial?

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Controller

```
 public ViewResult CreateFormModelConfigurarAreaItem()
{
     DatabaseEntities db=new DatabaseEntities();
     return View("FormModelConfigurarAreaItemRow", new FormModelConfigurarAreaItem{ Agrupaciones =  db.AgrupacionChequeo.toList()});
}
```

View

```
$("#addItem").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
    url: this.href,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
   });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes. You should add a new item by calling a controller, which 'controls' the model and view. Not creating a model in your view directly.